# How do I export 7, 14 and 28 day Active users in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

For years, we've been able to pull data out of the Active Users report on Google Analytics.  Now, when we try to export the data, we get an essentially blank spreadsheet.  It's now only one tab with none of the data we want/need.

Is there any another way to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the export feature from that report is broken for me too.

Google will probably fix it, especially if enough people report the issue.   Go to the report, click on the three dots icon in the top right of the page and select "send feedback".    Report that the export is broken.